# How to segue to a specific viewcontroller in a different storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

When you execute a segue back to a storyboard using a storyboard reference, it loads up the initial view controller for that storyboard.

I'm needing to segue to a view controller that is not my initial view controller from the other storyboard.

How do you accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Swift 3,

```
var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Another", bundle: nil)
  var vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NextViewController") as AnotherViewController
  self.show(vc, sender: self)
```

Comment: you have the right answer, but your syntax isn't updated

    `let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Another", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextViewController")
    self.show(vc, sender: self)`

Answer (score 5):

> I'm needing to segue to a view controller that is not my initial view controller from the other storyboard.
>
> How do you accomplish this?

When you fill out the info for the storyboard reference, provide the name of the other storyboard and the ID of the desired view controller.

[image]